# Max-height will not scale site

Tags: css, html, scale, responsive-design

I am able to get the width of my project to scale but not the height (tried in FireFox and Chrome and I understand IE will not work)

Heres the CSS I am using:

```
section.main 
{
 max-height: 100%; 
 max-width: 100%; 
 border: 1px solid black; 
 width: 1000px; 
 height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have this defined: body, html {height:100%} ?

Comment: yes as 

html, body
{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

Comment: html, body {margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%;}... not max-width, max-height.. but is this main section inside body tag directly? or there are other divs outside?

Comment: inside the body tag, unless I change it to the way you displayed below

Answer (score 4):

well, you specify a height of 800px. So your site is 800px height.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extend your site at 100% you need to add

```
section.main
{
  height:100%; width:100%
}
```

or

```
section.main
{
  min-height:100%; min-width:100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RQvLF/1/

for height:100%; you need a surrounding div that will have a height specified in pixels.
or you can give your section.main a height of needed pixels.

max-height:100%; and max-width:100%  means that this div must no be bigger then 100% in height and width:

as you can say:  `max-width:600px;` so that your inside content will not go bigger then 600px.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have :

```
html, body
{
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
}
```

For a div to have a % height, the parent's height must be defined.

Note that your border'll cause problems : the section will be 100% height + 2px. You may use :

```
section
{
box-sizing : border-box
}
```